# Moving files from Wep App to File Storage

Tags: azure, powershell, file-storage

I want to move the files in the Azure Web App(upload folder) to File Storage.

How can i do it?

**I want to move files that are too large at Ftp.
Can I send File Storage in a short way?**

Can I do it through Powershell? (or other option)

Comment: Do you want to copy the files in web app using FTP to on-premise then upload the pasted files to Azure file storage in your storage account?

Comment: Please edit your question with more details of what you are trying to do. It seems unclear right now.